# Custom name for grouping metrics with same tags

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-cloudwatch, micrometer, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

My application based on spring-boot and I'm using micrometer with AWS cloudwatch for collecting specific metrics. Faced an issue that it is hard to find needed metric if it has many additional tags, because of AWS naming metric groups (metrics with the same dimensions) by simple joining tags' names.

*Here is an example:*
[image]

At the same time, for default aws services' metrics here present readable titles.
[image]

Does anyone know how can I configure these titles? And can I configure them at all?

Answer (score 2):

You can't configure that. You'll see pretty labels on metrics publish by AWS services that integrate with CloudWatch in the background.

Custom metrics will have a top level namespace and then you'll have metrics grouped by different dimensions used (what you see in the screenshot).

I'm not familiar with spring boot or micrometer, but if you have the ability to configure it, you could try some of these things:

1. Split metrics into different namespaces (cache metrics for example could go into a separate namespace).
2. Remove some of the detail (do you need per instance metrics).
3. Move some dimensions into metric name (if you just want the info of the dimension value, but don't need the ability to aggregate and graph across that dimension, you can have it as part of the metric name).
4. Use search to find the metric you need.